# How to disable Validations when doing a Submit in the change event of a DropDown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal with a dropdown where, whenever an option is selected, a submit is made and the template is sent to the action to be edited and then returned. The problem is that Validations get in the way, is it possible to disable validations only for the change event of my dropdown? The Save button should work normally, but for the dropdown you must disable them.

```js
$('#pessoaNatureza').on('change', function (e) {    
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/725 ?

Comment: In clear..  The same link provided above by  @Shyju with an hash tag to what I think is the relevant comment: [#issuecomment-69816160](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/725#issuecomment-69816160)

Answer (score 0):

To disable a form:

```
$("#formId").validate().settings.ignore = "*";
```

To enable/renable a form:

```
$("#formId").validate().settings.ignore = ":hidden";
```